# One Square and one straight line(pipe)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, geometry

**Edited:**

> A farmer has a farm.The farm is a square whose sides have length 1. A single straight water pipe passes somewhere under the farm with depth one meter. He wants to dig furrows to find the pipe. The objective is to minimize the total length of furrows that are guaranteed to cross the pipe.
>   The furrows that he makes may be a set of line segments.

One solution of the problem is the diagonals of square but isn't minimum.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?  As stated, the question is unclear.  What does "directly under the farm" mean?  Can the pipe just clip one corner of the square farm?  A picture might help, especially if there are some constraints on the placement of the pipe.  As it stands, why should one believe that a single straight test line will necessarily find the pipe?

Comment: One answer to the problem is the diameters of the square.

Comment: Do you mean diagonals?  And, do you mean BOTH diagonals or just one? I don't think a single diagonal works (without more constraints on the pipe). As for both diagonals, from what you wrote I thought you wanted a straight groove, no?  If not, what are the conditions on the groove?

Comment: Yes both diagonals. The grooves must be direct lines.

Comment: I propose some conditions on the various lines: The house is a square (it doesn't really matter how big it is).  The pipe is a single straight line that passes *somewhere* under the house (it doesn't really matter how deep it is).  The digs that we make may be a curve, or a set of curves (we can approximate a curve arbitrarily with any number of line segments).  The objective is to minimize the total length of digs that are guaranteed to cross the pipe.  Is that all OK?

Comment: It seems that you want to say that the pipe passes through any two sides in a straight line

Comment: I edited my question. How can it be removed from the off-Topic؟

Comment: I think there is an interesting question here.  To rephrase, and possibly clarify, it:  Suppose a line intersects a square.  We note that the two diagonals, taken together, are guaranteed to intersect the line somewhere in the square. We ask if there is any configuration of line segments in the square which has this property and which has shorter total length than the combined length of the diagonals?  Seems interesting.  In the answer section, I showed that the diagonals are not minimal.  A more specific question would then be: is the 5 segment configuration described below optimal?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have a candidate for the smallest configuration (but can not prove it is optimal).  It does, however, beat the two diagonals.

Represent the square in the coordinate plane, with vertices at $$A = (-1,-1) \; B = (-1,1) \;C = (1, 1)\; D=  (1, -1)$$  Thus the sides have length 2 (that will simplify later calculations).  Now draw a horizontal segment on the x-axis from $$P = (-L, 0) \; to \; Q = (L,0)$$ so this segment has length 2L.  Now connect A and B to P and C and D to Q. The final figure looks like a capital H with angled sides.

[NOTE:  I tried to draw this figure here, but failed.  Sorry.]

Now, the length of my figure is a function of L, specifically: $$f(L) = 2L + 4\sqrt{1 + (1-L)^2}.$$  We seek L for which this is minimal.  It is easy to differentiate f and in so doing we see that the minimum comes when L = $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$.  The resulting configuration has total length ~ 5.464 whereas the two diagonals have total length ~ 5.657.  So the angled H is ahead, if not by much.

I have no idea at all how to decide if this configuration is minimal.

Comment: It is not minimum. Please see this image http://s3.picofile.com/file/8199409500/11.jpg

Comment: Fair enough!  And is that configuration known to be minimal?

Comment: My example is not still minimal but it's less than your solution.

Comment: Do you know what the minimal configuration is?